# Creating a raster from scratch in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to create raster structure with 3 columns and 3 rows (3x3). The raster resolution should be 10 m, and cell values should be set according to the attached picture. After that, I plan to reclassify it by replacing values greater than or equal to 140 with number 20, and all values that are less than 140 with number 10.

Any ideas how to accomplish that?

This is the picture with values

[image]

Answer (score 8):

1. Open a text editor.
2. Type the followings and save as `test.asc`:

   ```
   ncols 3
   nrows 3
   xllcorner 0
   yllcorner 0
   cellsize 10
   nodata_value -32768
   142 139 138
   140 137 135
   136 135 130
   ```

   If you know yllcorner/xllcorner, change `0`s. (ll: lower left)

In QGIS

3. Open an empty project. Select a metric CRS for the project from "Project - Properties... - CRS tab".
4. Go to "Layer Menu - Add Layer - Add Raster Layer...".
5. Specify file path and data type as in the image.

   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't have my laptop with me so I may not use the exact Qgis tools terms but you shall do something like this:

1. create a 3*3 grid with the desired resolution (in your case 10 meters)
2. create a field "value" where you can assign your values to each cell
3. rasterize your grid by using the value field as the "burn in value"
4. use the raster calculator to change your pixel values:

("raster@1" < 140) * 10+ ("raster@1" >= 140)* 20